# how to pass object to a function in python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, object, arguments

I have created a class in python as:

```
class dataframe():
    #    
    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, fcsv, colp, label,DataFrame):

        label = r'\textbf{' + label +'}'

        self.fcsv  = fcsv  
        self.colp  = colp
        self.label = label
        self.dfr   = pd.DataFrame()
```

As you can noticed, each object would be a data-frame with some characteristics.

Consequently in the main code I crate the following list of objects as:

```
DFC =[]
DFC.append(dataframe('econ_real' ,'r','real price'       ,pd.DataFrame))
DFC.append(dataframe('autoarimax','b','autoarimax model' ,pd.DataFrame))
DFC.append(dataframe('benchmark' ,'g','benchmark model'  ,pd.DataFrame))
```

I would like to pass some of them to a function as argument.

I have tried something like taht:

```
sp='2017-03-01 00:00:00'
ep='2017-05-01 00:00:00'
plot_hh(DFC[:].dfr[sp:ep,'A'])
```

Basically, I would like to pass the dataframes plus their characteristics and some of their row and columns, the ones that I would like to print.

Unfortunately, this seems to not work. Indeed, the plot subroutine gives me an invalid syntax error, where the plot subroutines is:

```
def plot_hh(DFC[:].dfr):

  print('hello')
```

and this is ho I fill up the dataframes:

```
for idf in range(0,3):
  DFC[idf].dfr = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=';',index_col=0, header = 0)
```

I have tried to study function and arguments but I am not able to work this out.

Thanks for any kind of help.
Best regards

Comment: You aren't using the `DataFrame` argument to `__init__`; you can get rid of it. In fact, this may be a case where inheritance *is* appropriate; `dataframe` could be a subclass of `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: `def __init__(self, fcsv, colp, label,DataFrame):` you are using a variable name of `DataFrame` (which is bad as it potentially shadows the class name, maybe use `dfr` as the variable/param name. But then in the body of the init you do `self.dfr = pd.DataFrame()` essentially ignoring the dataframe passed into the class and jsut setting `self.dfr` to a new, empty dataframe.

Comment: Dear @TomDalton, Thanks for the suggestions. I have change self.dfr = pd.DataFrame() to self.dfr = dfr accordingly.  I have add the part where I fill up the dataframe.

Comment: @chepner. I am not using it but I will use it. As a a consequence I can not get rid of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You get an invalid syntax in your plot routine, try changing:

```
def plot_hh(DFC[:].dfr):
  print('hello')
```

To:

```
def plot_hh(df):
  print('hello')
  print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It seems to not working. I have done the following:
plot_hh(DFC[:])
and def plot_hh(DFC):   Basically, I pass al the objects